# Error in multipart file upload: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartfile

We have an API to upload document. We got a very strange error and we got this error for the first time on our server.
This is the API structure.

```
@PatchMapping(value = "{id}/file-upload", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public CommonResponse updatePersonalKyc(@PathVariable("id") long customerId,
                                        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
}
```

Here is the error stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:221) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1226) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1070) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:551) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:336) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:632) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1178) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1012) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at com.epl.retail.configuration.Slf4jMDCFilter.doFilterInternal(Slf4jMDCFilter.java:69) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.epl.retail.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:132) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTrackingFilter.java:142) ~[applicationinsights-web-2.6.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_312]
```

The API throw an Error:

```
Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

Here the config regarding multipart file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size: 20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size: 20MB
```

Not able to identify the issue.
Anyone help to identify the issue?

Comment: FWIW you should set `max-request-size` a bit larger than `max-file-size` to allow for overhead. E.g. a 20MB file will fail with this config since the request itself will be larger than 20MB.